# TeXShop autocompletion gone crazy!

Tags: editors, texshop, auto-completion

Quite often when typing in the TeXShop editor, weird snippets of text suddenly appear where I am typing.  Usually, it's an word or a couple of words, and usually they are completely unrelated to anything I've been typing or doing recently, e.g. I type "x" and the word "xenotransplant" appears.  I can't figure out what's causing this, or how to make it stop.

I am running OS 10.15.7 on a 2019 Macbook Pro and I am running TeXShop 4.60.  (However, I have had the same problem with earlier OS and TeXShop versions.)  In Preferences -> Source, the Dictionary setting is Automatic Language, and none of the boxes under Speall Checking is checked.  Under Preferences -> Editor, Check Spelling is checked.

Comment: I think Skynet just became self-aware.  Welcome to the site.  Hasta la vista, baby!

Comment: Make sure that everything under Edit->Substitutions is unchecked.